# SQL Server : update query execute indefinitely

Tags: sql-server, datetime

Currently I am using SQL Server 2005. I got a trigger event which is create csv file when a datetime column is changed. When I try to update the datetime of a record in the database, it keep executing the query until I force to stop it. May I know what is the possible problem that will causes this ? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

This is my update query.

```
UPDATE S_xxx
SET DatePosted = CAST('2015-08-26 15:49:16.000' AS datetime)
WHERE TrxNo = 'RCACP1000000420'
```

This is the code for the trigger event.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_S_xxx_ForUpdate]
ON [dbo].[S_xxx]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    IF Update(DatePosted) --AND DatePosted NOT NULL
    BEGIN   
        DECLARE @pSQL as VARCHAR(500)
        DECLARE @pdate as datetime 
        DECLARE @ptime as varchar(30)
        DECLARE @pFileName as VARCHAR(100)
        DECLARE @pBizDate as varchar (30)
        DECLARE @pLocationCode as varchar (50)
        DECLARE @nNewValue as DATETIME
        DECLARE @pFilePath as varchar (50)
        DECLARE @pLogMsgString as varchar (500)
        DECLARE @pBatch as varchar (100)
        DECLARE @pLogName as varchar (100)
        DECLARE @pExecBatch as varchar (100)

        SELECT @nNewValue=a.DatePosted -- Get the Old and New values
        FROM inserted a

        SET @pdate = @nNewValue
        SET @pBizDate = convert(varchar(30),@pdate,103) 
        SET @ptime = convert(varchar(30),@pdate,101) 

        SELECT @pLocationCode = memCtlCharCode       
        FROM JTBCtlTab  
        WHERE strCtlCode = 'POS2icms_LOCATIONCODE';

        SELECT @pFilePath = memCtlCharCode       
        FROM JTBCtlTab  
        WHERE strCtlCode = 'POS2icms_TARGETFOLDER';

        SET @pFileName = @pFilePath + convert(varchar(30),@pdate,112) + '_' + REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 108), ':','') + '.csv'
        SET @pBatch = convert(varchar(30),@pdate,112) + '_' + REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 108), ':','') + '.bat'
        SET @pLogName = convert(varchar(30),@pdate,112) + '_' + REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 108), ':','') + '.log'
        SET @pExecBatch = '''' + @pFilePath + @pBatch + ''''

        SET @pSQL = 'sqlcmd -S DEV-WEB-PC01 -d POSJDB -E ' +
         '-Q "set nocount on; SELECT ' + '''' + @pLocationCode + '''' + ',' + '''' + @pBizDate + '''' + ',' +
         'SUM(COALESCE(S.Amount, 0) + COALESCE(N.Amount, 0) + COALESCE(R.Amount, 0))' +
         'From dbo.S_xxx AS H LEFT JOIN dbo.SER_TRX_CASHSALES AS S ON  H.TrxNo = S.TrxNo ' +
         'LEFT JOIN dbo.SER_TRX_SPORDER_NEWITEM AS N ON H.TrxNo = N.TrxNo ' +
         'LEFT JOIN dbo.SER_TRX_SPORDER_REPAIR AS R ON H.TrxNo = R.TrxNo ' +
         'Where convert(varchar(30),H.DatePosted,101) = ' + '''' + @ptime + '''' +
         -- 'and S.is_void = 0' +
         '" -h-1 -s "," -W -o "' + @pFileName + '"';   

    set @pLogMsgString = @pSQL 
    exec spWriteStringToFile @pLogMsgString , @pFilePath, @pLogName
    exec spWriteStringToFile @pLogMsgString , @pFilePath, @pBatch 

    Print @pExecBatch
    EXEC xp_cmdshell @pExecBatch
END
```

Comment: Probably is blocked by another query/transaction

Comment: As a side note: your trigger is horribly broken. `inserted` is a table that can contain 0, 1 or *multiple* rows. So `SELECT @nNewValue=a.DatePosted FROM inserted a` will obtain a value from *one* of those rows and *ignore* all others.

Comment: And you're trying to run another piece of SQL on a different connection that is trying to read from the same table - of course it blocks, because you're still inside the original transaction that's holding an exclusive lock on that table.

Comment: How big is your dataset? maybe the `SQLCMD` just takes forever to export? You'd need to check database activity to be sure? Is the file even created? Is SQLCMD runing? Regardless this is a very bad idea that is bound to be unreliable

Answer (score 1):

My tip is deadlock. Your trigger is running in the transaction and you run external tool sqlcmd which use another transaction and waits for lock on the table. But the table is already locked and you transaction is waiting for external tool.

Try create and export the CSV directly from the trigger without using external tools. Or execute the external tool but don't wait until process exit.